# Getting a "Faceting variables must have at least one value" error only when using ggplot2 in R Markdown; what does this mean?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm using a for loop to create several boxplots as part of an R Markdown report.  Most of my boxplots print successfully, while others for some reason fail to print, instead giving me the following error: "Error: Faceting variables must have at least one value".

Here is my data for one of my boxplots that gave an error:

```
structure(list(target_id = c("ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304",
"ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304",
"ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304",
"ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304",
"ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304",
"ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304", "ENST00000390304"), tpm = c(0.0805275227988995,
0, 0, 0, 13.82501606306, 0, 0.899651016904527, 0, 3.97161098682224,
25.4470126325026, 14.1717230551304, 8.47283747191736, 11.9239827469873,
1.15292796701229, 4.89325150388971, 38.1766608035109, 42.117834900921,
5.04752697725949, 14.6501301179727, 2.31319103570497, 0.822267881088558
), condition = c("A", "A", "A", "B",
"B", "A", "B", "A", "C",
"D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
"D", "D", "D", "D", "C"), hgnc_symbol = c("IGLV3-27",
"IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27",
"IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27",
"IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27",
"IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-27")), .Names = c("target_id", "tpm", "condition",
"hgnc_symbol"), row.names = c(218969L, 218970L, 218971L, 218972L,
218973L, 218974L, 218975L, 218976L, 1739400L, 1739401L, 1739402L,
1739403L, 1739404L, 1739405L, 1739406L, 1739407L, 1739408L, 1739409L,
1739410L, 1739411L, 1739412L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
genes <- head(results_table$ens_gene, 25) 

for (i in 1:length(genes)) {
  curr_gene <- genes[i]
  curr_data <- final_output[which(final_output$ensembl_gene_id==curr_gene),]
  curr_data <- subset(curr_data, select=c(target_id, tpm, condition, hgnc_symbol))
  hgnc_symbol <- unique(curr_data$hgnc_symbol)

  print({
    ggplot(curr_data, aes(x = condition, y = tpm, fill=condition)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour=NA, lwd=0.2, color="grey18") + 
    stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', color="grey18") + 
    geom_jitter(size=0.8, width=0.2) + 
    facet_wrap(~target_id) + 
    guides(fill=FALSE) + 
    theme_bw() +  
    labs(title=paste(hgnc_symbol, "_", curr_gene, sep="")) + 
    labs(x="condition") + labs(y="TPM") + 
    theme(text = element_text(size=9), 
      strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10), 
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=12),
      axis.text.y = element_text(size=9),
      title = element_text(size=12),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size=12),
      axis.title.y = element_text(size=12))})
}
```

I know that, for the boxplot of the data I've given above, faceting is not strictly necessary, since the plot will only have one facet; however, this is relevant to some of the other boxplots generated by this code, which is why it is in the code.

When I print this same plot as a .png (not as part of an R Markdown report), it prints successfully, which leads me to believe that my issue has to do with R Markdown.  Has anyone encountered this problem before and figured out a fix for it?

Comment: it works fine on win 7 / R 3.2.3 / ggplot 2.1.0 / knitr 1.12

Comment: It might help if you show the full snippet of code that creates the plots, including the loop and any code external to the loop that might affect values in the loop. Also, the best way to provide data samples for R-related questions is by pasting in the output of `dput()`, as in `dput(my_data_frame)`.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10.  I've updated my question to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I had this problem and it was resolved by re-starting my R session.

Answer (score 0):

If the error happens during knitting, but you can run the chunk within the R markdown file and it plots successfully, then try emptying the cache folder associated with the Rmd file. This worked for me. Restarting my R session did not work.

Comment: how do you do this?